# GridDB on arm64

Tags: database, griddb

At this moment(12.10.22) griddb is available on some processors based on arm64 in MC like Rock Pi 4B?
Im trying to using guide from here https://griddb.net/en/blog/griddb-on-arm-time-series-database-for-your-raspberry-pi/ step by step, but get some errors from ./configure and make.
Ty for answer

Comment: You need to provide the steps you tried and the errors you faced.